# Time Zone issue in IMAP

Tags: php, timezone, imap

I am fetching emails from Gmail.
when i searched latest emails from Gmail using PHP Imap after a date time
It is giving me repeated result or not accurate.

Code sample which i am using to get next latest messages after a date time.
I know these are Time Zones issue.
I am storing messages in my DB.

How to get rid from These time zones issue?

```
if($lastMsgTimeDate == '') {
 $date = date("j F Y H:i:s");
}else{
 $date = date("j F Y H:i:s", strtotime($lastMsgTimeDate));
}

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'since "'.$date.'"' );
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: I don't think timezones are an issue if you are using fixed datetime values. How is it returning duplicate emails? Do the duplicate emails fall within your search date criteria?

Answer (score 1):

As PHP uses IMAP2 search facilities which don't allow searching by time, this probably this could be your timezone issue solved.

Make use of last UID rather than date.

Search all recent messages and if it gets to the last UID then Exit the search

Comment: ok.. i will try with IMAP UID search..
more can you please give me little bit example how can i search imap using UID ?